# Can Windows Controls works with WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

We have Win Forms application uses the 3rd party windows native controls. Can these controls used with WPF application?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course, that's what the `WindowsFormsHost` WPF control is for!

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751761.aspx to do it in code.

Or: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742875.aspx to do it in XAML.

Comment: By the way, that took all of 10 seconds to find out with a quick Google ;-)

Comment: I like to know, are there any hidden complication using windows controls with WPF.

Comment: I just thought it'd be nice to mention the name of the control required. It can be found in the toolbox as well and the OP might just not have found it :-)

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, aside from the possibility of poor performance and limitations on graphics rendering, but I wouldn't mind betting your library vendor has a WPF version :)

Comment: @Andy, I yet to explore the WPF world. After MFC and WinForms, WPF is another major break.. Thanks for answer

Comment: I was in the same boat four months ago, now I love WPF, but I still find it has teething issues.  WPF apps also don't seem to have the performance of WinForms - I find they lag sometimes like Java apps on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. However, if you can use a WPF control instead do it.